# Django Rest Framework: Remove Appended "[]" from List Parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django rest framework application set up with two packages: One's called djangorestframework-camel-case (to "camelizes" the parameters in the API docs) and the other is drf-spectacular (to automatically generate Swagger docs for my API).

The camel case package also has the effect that it causes parameters from the request data sent from the frontend (in camelCase) to be received in the Python backend in snake_case. However, I just found out that when one of the requests from the frontend contains a list of data, lets say `dataList = ["1", "2", "3"]`, the parameter is received in the Python backend as a dictionary with the key `data_list[]`. Is there a setting to remove that `[]` at the end? Its messing up with the rest of my logic.

Comment: So, you get `dataList[]=["1","2","3"]` and want to transform it to `dataList=["1","2","3"]`?

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to know if I can disable the array notation for the key name

Comment: Take a peek at the answer. I hope I understood correctly. If this is not what you need, let me know

Comment: It may be just me, but Im unable to see your answer :(